# add docker container as data source for grafana

Tags: laravel, docker, grafana

I have four docker containers running:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                NAMES
97b1f0d98b1c        kamon/grafana_graphite   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       80-81/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8125->8125/udp, 0.0.0.0:8126->8126/tcp, 0.0.0.0:40001->3000/tcp   kamon-grafana-dashboard
79b9032b9ed4        engie_image              "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                                        engie_cont
0a1fdd8b830c        piha_image               "docker-php-entryp..."   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          9000/tcp                                                                             piha_cont
61c8a4c80180        mysql:5.6                "docker-entrypoint..."   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp                                                              diba_cont
```

2-4 are designed to launch default laravel project that is accessible via:
localhost:8080

The first container was taken from this image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/kamon/grafana_graphite/

Now the idea is to add container (engie_cont) as DataSource.
I login into grafana as user: admin pass: admin, go to add DataSource and get error:
[image]

Why can't I add URL (localhost:8080) that is accessible from browser (Chrome) as DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try is to change the Access to proxy. Direct mode is direct from your browser and you are probably getting a CORS (Cross Origin) error. The default is proxy and direct mode is only for special cases where you want to send credentials from your browser to the data source.

EDIT: This is a special case.

You can get the real error from the grafana logs:

1. Get the container id (97b1f0d98b1c in your case)
2. `docker exec -i -t 97b1f0d98b1c cat /var/log/supervisor/grafana-webapp.log`

It is probably a connection error.

1. Change back to direct mode.
2. Find the docker host ip address: `sudo ip addr show docker0` (it was 172.17.0.1 when I tested)
3. Change the Url to `http://172.17.0.1:8080`

[image]

Comment: I tried that ofc, in case of proxy I get "internal server error"

Comment: Ran the Kamon Grafana/Graphite docker container myself and got it working. It is quite different from the standard Grafana docker container so I can understand that it was hard to get this working. Anyway, updated answer.